# segregate the Test data in cell A and B and create a new sheet with their individual combo as listed in row 8

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The example has been updated through the image provided below. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: "macros" is the best you can do for tags? Your title is longer than your description of the problem.  You should work on your question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm doing this for the first time, so I didn't know what to tag it under as I'm new to VBA

Comment: I am not trying to give you a hard time.  Put the information from your comment in a formatted way into the question (not a comment).  Tags?  How about add "excel" and "spreadsheet" to "macros"? :)

Comment: Please try to explain this better. What is the input? What is the output? (Please enter data as formatted text, not as an image.) What have you tried? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' hey G-Man I've shared an updated example with the image, hope this helps. I'm sorry that I'm not well versed with the technical terms used hence I've tried explaining to the best of my abilities.

Comment: You posted a screenshot from Excel on Android. Only desktop version of Excel supports macros, do you have access to that version too?